# Cuda Thrust memory management

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu, thrust

I wrote this code below:

```
 unsigned int* addrArray = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*DATASETROWS);
 thrust::exclusive_scan(binaryDataSet,binaryDataSet+(sizeof(unsigned int)*DATASETROWS),addrArray);
 free(addrArray);
```

binaryDataSet is `unsigned int*` type and I have no problems with allocating, processing data in this part of memory and freeing it. But `addrArray` causes problems. aftter running program i get following error:

> `*** glibc detected *** ./prog: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x000000000180be10 ***` and memory map.

This code wont generate this error when I use `cudaFree(addrArray)` instead, but later it will cause segmentation fault or glibc malloc memory corruption problem. For example running this:

```
unsigned int* addrArray = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*DATASETROWS);
thrust::exclusive_scan(binaryDataSet,binaryDataSet+(sizeof(unsigned int)*DATASETROWS),addrArray);
const unsigned int compactArraySize = addrArray[DATASETROWS-1] - 1;
printf("%u\n",compactArraySize)
float* compactMinorClass = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*DATASETCOLS*compactArraySize);
```

Will generate segmentation fault when trying to malloc memory on `compactMinorClass` pointer(`printf` gives correct output, so prefixsum is calculated correctly and output is saved in addrArray as should be).
To build this program I set flags for g++ and nvcc as following:

`GXXFLAGS:=  -O3 -Wall -Wextra -m64 -std=c++0x`

`NVCCFLAGS:= -Xcompiler -Wall -Xcompiler -Wextra -m64 -arch=sm_11`

(I have GeForce310M so I have to set sm_11) 
So my question is why running this thrust function generates errors, why I can't free memory allocated on host using `free()` ?

Comment: what's the type of binaryDataSet?

Comment: The question states: binaryDataSet is `unsigned int*` type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
thrust::exclusive_scan(binaryDataSet,binaryDataSet+(sizeof(unsigned int)*DATASETROWS),addrArray);
```

Try this instead:

```
thrust::exclusive_scan(binaryDataSet,binaryDataSet+(DATASETROWS),addrArray);
```

The intention here is to do pointer arithmetic, not byte arithmetic.  And likewise in your second code sample.

I'm also not sure it's a good idea to specify:

```
-std=c++0x
```

But I don't know for sure that it's the source of any of your problems.

You definitely should not do `cudaFree` on an ordinary host pointer.